# Is there a way to see cpp function description as a hint in qml

Tags: qt, qml

Lets say I have a method in cpp like this with a description

```
//! This is my test function
Q_INVOKABLE void test(QString q, QString b);
```

and I invoke the method in QML like this

```
TestClass.test("String1", "String2")
```

Now, If I hover my mouse over `TestClass.test`, the Qt Editor just says `Function`. Is there any way, I can see the method description in CPP inside QML invokation?

Comment: You should create a suggestion for it against the QTCREATORBUG project on https://bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: @Mitch, I will suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but from my knowledge, it isn't possible.

Comment: Hmm.. I think this should have been there. Its pretty bad and makes it difficult in qml side to repeatedly go and check the cpp part

Comment: It is like it is and we can't do anything with it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse on `TestClass.test` Qt Creator does indeed only hint `Function` but if you trigger an autocomplete inside the parenthesis (ctrl + space) it will show a tooltip with the name of the different parameters.

Comment: Agreed. But comments would have been more helpful for referring to the code in the future or for someone new. That's why I asked. I can understand probably the feature is not there